# Making Axios request to Nodejs/Expressjs server on different port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm trying to make a POST request using Axios to the Nodejs/Expressjs server that I've made. I've tried over and over to make a POST request and all I get is a "Network Error". I've also tried to run the server and Axios code on separate computers on my network.

Axios Code:

```js
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8080/test", {
    first: "Testing"
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })

  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

ExpressJS server code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = 8080

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-origin", "*")
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET, POST")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
})
app.post("/test", function(req, res) {
    res.send("This works!")
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening on port 8080"));
```

Comment: maybe `axios.post('localhost:8080/test', { })`

Comment: I've done that now its just getting a request timeout

Comment: Try `axios.post('http://localhost:8080', {`

Comment: That did not work either it gave me a network error. the /test is still giving me a request timeout

Comment: Is your api working from a REST testing tool like Postman ?

Comment: There's more to supporting CORS than just responding with a couple of headers. For one, you also need to be able to handle pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests. I highly recommend you use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package instead of trying to _roll-your-own_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one issue in CORS middleware, Need to call next function,

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = 8080

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-origin", "*")
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,POST,OPTIONS")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next();
})
app.post("/test", function (req, res) {
    res.send("This works!")
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening on port 8080"));
```

Comment: Well spotted however OP's `POST` request is non-simple and will send a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request which needs to be handled

Comment: Yes  preflight `OPTIONS` request needs to be handled  @Phil

Comment: How would I go about handling that options request?